# PHPWord: Spaces Treated as Line Breaks Issue

Tags: php, phpword

I'm facing an issue with PHPWord while reading Word documents (.docx). It appears that spaces are occasionally treated as line breaks, causing unexpected formatting. I've reviewed both my code and the document, but the problem persists.

```
$fileDoc = $request->file('template');
$docObject = IOFactory::createReader('Word2007')->load($fileDoc);
```

Comment: Please read [mre] and [edit] your question to include *all* necessary code and data to make it possible to reproduce the problem.